# How to scroll overflow:scroll div while dragging object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, overflow, jquery-ui-draggable

Let's say I have a draggable element with id `#draggable`. I also have a div that contains a list of droppable divs with id `#list`. But the container div is limited in height, so it can display only 3 droppable divs at once (A, B and C). That container div is set to `overflow:scroll`.

How could I manage to get the container div to scroll when I'm dragging the `#draggable` element over it? Because right now I can't drop the element on last droppable elements that are hidden by the overflow (D, E, F, G).

[**See this fiddle for demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/v80kppez/1/)

```
<span id="draggable">draggable</span>
<hr>
<div style="height:200px;overflow:scroll">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, you can that if you drop the element **under** the `overflow:scroll` div, it actually drops on the hidden droppable divs!

How to deal with those issues?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020798/jquery-ui-draggable-scroll-issue

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes the accepted answer helped me

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for you is to move `#draggable` div inside `div` with `overflow:scroll` attached like this:

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow:scroll">
  <span id="draggable">draggable</span>
  <hr/>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/matikucharski/v80kppez/2/

Comment: @bob - please accept this answer if this one helped you :)

Comment: No I can't do this I need the draggable elements to be outside of the div with overflow.

Comment: So you can have it outside and just copy the element to the div with overflow on drag and resume it on drop.